# Accessing MYSQL log files on AWS RDS with MYSQL Workbench - WMI Error

Tags: mysql, logging, wmi

I am trying to access the MYSQL database server logs via MYSQL Workbench, but I'm running into issues. In MYSQL Workbench, when I go to Server>Server Logs I get prompted to enter my Admin user password. After I enter the Admin password I get an error saying "Could not acquire management access for administration" and a runtime error that says "Could not initialize WMI interface: Workbench.wmiOpenSession(): Could not connect to target machine".

I've looked through other posts but can't seem to figure out what to do. I would assume from the error I need to start WMI on my AWS RDS Windows server, but not sure if that's correct or how to do that. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: see the manual https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Comment: thanks, I've seen the manual. I'm trying to stay away from changing RDS configuration and parameter groups because I don't want to cause other issues. My ultimate goal is to access the logs using MYSQL Workbench. I've done it before, so I know it can be done, but I'm stuck on this WMI error.

Comment: that is a server configuration i doubt that it will be possible